# function to make some divs disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

i have a 3divs inside of a container and when i click div number 1 i want the others to disappear
but it works only when i click the "rock" div

The parent div is called "choices" in the JS file
i am trying to loop over the child divs to keep the clicked one and hide the others

```js
choices.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let currentTag = e.target.tagName;
  let current;
  if (e.target.className !== "choices") {
    // to make sure the user click on the choices only
    switch (
      currentTag // to get the div element even if the user clicked the svg or the path
    ) {
      case "DIV":
        current = e.target;
        console.log(current);
        break;
      case "svg":
        current = e.target.parentElement;
        console.log(current);
        break;
      case "path":
        current = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        console.log(current);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    current.setAttribute("chosen", "true");
    for (i = 0; i < choicesList.length; i++) {
      choicesList[i].hasAttribute("chosen") ?
        "" :
        choices.removeChild(choicesList[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="choices" vassel="true">
  <!-- Scissors -->
  <div class="scissors">
    <svg class="scissors" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="51" height="58">
              <path
                class="scissors"
                fill="#3B4262"
                d="M13.971 25.702l6.012-8.415c-2.499-.415-7.088-.507-10.846 3.235C3.212 26.421.812 39.163.312 42.248L15.37 57.24c2.711-.232 14.713-1.827 26.279-13.34.122-.249 2.94-2.321.636-4.614-1.1-1.095-2.919-1.074-4.042.044-.572.57-1.461.577-2.021.02-.56-.557-.552-1.443.02-2.012l4.087-4.069c2.076-2.067.119-5.555-2.78-4.717l-3.345 2.851c-.611.53-1.52.439-2.022-.14-.519-.597-.408-1.503.183-2.013 11.687-10.208 9.98-8.979 17.5-15.995 2.809-2.329-.725-6.447-3.493-4.09L28.182 25.45c-.529.448-1.34.457-1.86-.02-.601-.517-.615-1.262-.222-1.85L38.787 3.944c1.854-2.5-1.795-5.277-3.749-2.757L16.28 27.307c-.452.65-1.364.8-1.985.345a1.377 1.377 0 01-.323-1.95z"
              />
            </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- rock -->
  <div class="rock">
    <svg class="rock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48">
              <path
              class="rock"
                fill="#3B4262"
                d="M45.06 12.22c-.642-8.096-9.734-7.269-9.734-7.269-3.837-6.765-9.832-1.865-9.832-1.865-4.606-6.63-10.38-.486-10.38-.486-9.957-1.074-9.571 7.066-9.571 7.066-.234 2.588 1.403 10.593 1.403 10.593-1.477-4.614-4.68-.784-4.68-.784-3.94 6.078-.975 9.405-.975 9.405 5.33 6.246 16.688 13.743 16.688 13.743 4.113 2.356 2.373 4.457 2.373 4.457l24.876-4.11.571-4.718c3.782-11.436-.739-26.032-.739-26.032z"
              />
            </svg>
  </div>

  <!-- Paper -->
  <div class="paper">
    <svg class="paper" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="49" height="59">
              <path
              class="paper"
                fill="#3B4262"
                d="M47.125 11.832a2.922 2.922 0 00-1.232-.198c-.57.04-1.029.271-1.302.65-1.604 2.248-2.919 6.493-3.979 9.905-.486 1.577-1.14 3.688-1.612 4.69-.493-2.807.064-13.09.28-17.05l.003-.064c.15-2.751.17-3.234.138-3.446-.238-1.509-.843-2.5-1.799-2.943-.966-.45-2.22-.25-3.572.563-.677.41-.865 1.816-1.446 8.19l-.002.028c-.32 3.502-1.058 11.566-1.965 12.91-1.023-1.88-2.431-12.555-3.039-17.176-.425-3.236-.673-5.094-.84-5.655-.35-1.176-1.83-2.176-3.295-2.232-1.22-.06-2.22.56-2.698 1.638-.894.995-.578 4.292.41 12.102.47 3.718 1.44 11.395.83 12.257-1.219-.133-3.31-4.942-6.215-14.299-.816-2.62-1.068-3.408-1.318-3.753-.494-1.202-2.172-2.129-3.676-2.024a3.183 3.183 0 00-.377.049c-.787.156-2.584.881-2.2 4.226 1.06 4.637 2.213 8.041 3.331 11.346l.023.066c.669 1.98 1.302 3.85 1.89 5.925 1.385 4.9.846 7.94.84 7.975-.046.312-.143.503-.288.57a.556.556 0 01-.195.045c-.44.03-1.098-.26-1.437-.45-.776-1.482-4.636-8.544-8.134-9.524l-.126-.037-.127.012c-1.283.121-2.226.606-2.803 1.441-.914 1.32-.535 3.002-.444 3.34l.052.12c.028.051 2.834 5.165 3.268 7.544.374 2.04 2.311 4.25 3.869 6.026l.064.073c.508.58.946 1.083 1.292 1.548 4.519 4.713 11.665 8.677 11.723 8.71.892.657 1.387 1.293 1.44 1.84a.798.798 0 01-.16.58l-.155.162.988.96 18.853-1.324.804-3.684c2.486-10.402 1.967-19.272 1.958-19.33.01-.327.706-3.483 1.266-6.033l.017-.065c1.117-5.08 2.505-11.4 2.772-13.803.116-1.028-.542-1.972-1.675-2.401z"
              />
            </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the link for codepen : https://codepen.io/omarmahdy/pen/JjpEMaV

Comment: So you want if someone click on rock the other two will disappear? After they disappear do you also want to make them appear again?

Comment: no i dont want to , after choosing one div i want the result to show then try again btn to reset the game

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your child selector. My suggestion is to use `querySelectorAll()` and add a second class to all options. I created a working fork here: https://codepen.io/foorschtbar/pen/OJQWZJJ

```js
const choicesList = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");
```

```html
 <!-- Scissors -->
<div class="scissors choice">
 [...]
</div>
<!-- Rock -->
<div class="rock choice">
  [...]
</div>
<!-- Paper -->
<div class="paper choice">
  [...]
</div>
```

(i hope i understand your problem right and is now fixed)

Comment: it didn's solve the problem since when i click one it only removes one div and i need to remove all the rest

Comment: Sorry, I am new to codepen. I forgot to save my changes. Try the link again.

Comment: Please do not add just to a codepen. Answers and questions always must be self-containign and not purely relay on external resources. If the link to your codepen content changes, is removed or not accessible then your entire answer will become worthless. As such include code always in your answer or question directly. Use a stack snippet (`Ctrl + M` or the `<>`-button) to incldue a code snippet that can be executed directly on this site.

Comment: @tacoshy you are completely right, but i think the main problem was the wrong usage of the selector and my suggestion is right. The codepan was an addon. A downvote is not fair :(

Comment: It is because your answer is currently way to broad and just refers to an external resource. Add the code in a snippet directly and show how your answer would solve this issue. Then it would be a valid answer for SO.

Comment: foorschtbar's answer is actually working and a good solution.

Comment: foorschtbar thanks alot it's working

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should apply a CSS-class with `classList.add('class-name)` to all the child div elements of `choices`:
`document.querySelectorAll('.choices div').forEach(el => el.classList.add('class-name');`

Then you remove this class for the clicked element after wards. That CSS-Class only needs to contain: `display: none;`

```js
var choices = document.querySelector('.choices');
    
choices.addEventListener('click', e => {
  var scissors = document.querySelector('.scissors'),
      rock = document.querySelector('.rock'),
      paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
  document.querySelectorAll('.choices div').forEach(el => el.classList.add('d-none'));
  
  if (e.target.classList.contains('scissors')) {
    scissors.classList.remove('d-none');   
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains('rock')) {
    rock.classList.remove('d-none');   
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains('paper')) {
    paper.classList.remove('d-none');   
  } 
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices" vassel="true">
  <!-- Scissors -->
  <div class="scissors">
    <svg class="scissors" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="51" height="58">
              <path
                class="scissors"
                fill="#3B4262"
                d="M13.971 25.702l6.012-8.415c-2.499-.415-7.088-.507-10.846 3.235C3.212 26.421.812 39.163.312 42.248L15.37 57.24c2.711-.232 14.713-1.827 26.279-13.34.122-.249 2.94-2.321.636-4.614-1.1-1.095-2.919-1.074-4.042.044-.572.57-1.461.577-2.021.02-.56-.557-.552-1.443.02-2.012l4.087-4.069c2.076-2.067.119-5.555-2.78-4.717l-3.345 2.851c-.611.53-1.52.439-2.022-.14-.519-.597-.408-1.503.183-2.013 11.687-10.208 9.98-8.979 17.5-15.995 2.809-2.329-.725-6.447-3.493-4.09L28.182 25.45c-.529.448-1.34.457-1.86-.02-.601-.517-.615-1.262-.222-1.85L38.787 3.944c1.854-2.5-1.795-5.277-3.749-2.757L16.28 27.307c-.452.65-1.364.8-1.985.345a1.377 1.377 0 01-.323-1.95z"
              />
            </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- rock -->
  <div class="rock selection">
    <svg class="rock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48">
              <path
              class="rock"
                fill="#3B4262"
                d="M45.06 12.22c-.642-8.096-9.734-7.269-9.734-7.269-3.837-6.765-9.832-1.865-9.832-1.865-4.606-6.63-10.38-.486-10.38-.486-9.957-1.074-9.571 7.066-9.571 7.066-.234 2.588 1.403 10.593 1.403 10.593-1.477-4.614-4.68-.784-4.68-.784-3.94 6.078-.975 9.405-.975 9.405 5.33 6.246 16.688 13.743 16.688 13.743 4.113 2.356 2.373 4.457 2.373 4.457l24.876-4.11.571-4.718c3.782-11.436-.739-26.032-.739-26.032z"
              />
            </svg>
  </div>

  <!-- Paper -->
  <div class="paper selection">
    <svg class="paper" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="49" height="59">
              <path
              class="paper"
                fill="#3B4262"
                d="M47.125 11.832a2.922 2.922 0 00-1.232-.198c-.57.04-1.029.271-1.302.65-1.604 2.248-2.919 6.493-3.979 9.905-.486 1.577-1.14 3.688-1.612 4.69-.493-2.807.064-13.09.28-17.05l.003-.064c.15-2.751.17-3.234.138-3.446-.238-1.509-.843-2.5-1.799-2.943-.966-.45-2.22-.25-3.572.563-.677.41-.865 1.816-1.446 8.19l-.002.028c-.32 3.502-1.058 11.566-1.965 12.91-1.023-1.88-2.431-12.555-3.039-17.176-.425-3.236-.673-5.094-.84-5.655-.35-1.176-1.83-2.176-3.295-2.232-1.22-.06-2.22.56-2.698 1.638-.894.995-.578 4.292.41 12.102.47 3.718 1.44 11.395.83 12.257-1.219-.133-3.31-4.942-6.215-14.299-.816-2.62-1.068-3.408-1.318-3.753-.494-1.202-2.172-2.129-3.676-2.024a3.183 3.183 0 00-.377.049c-.787.156-2.584.881-2.2 4.226 1.06 4.637 2.213 8.041 3.331 11.346l.023.066c.669 1.98 1.302 3.85 1.89 5.925 1.385 4.9.846 7.94.84 7.975-.046.312-.143.503-.288.57a.556.556 0 01-.195.045c-.44.03-1.098-.26-1.437-.45-.776-1.482-4.636-8.544-8.134-9.524l-.126-.037-.127.012c-1.283.121-2.226.606-2.803 1.441-.914 1.32-.535 3.002-.444 3.34l.052.12c.028.051 2.834 5.165 3.268 7.544.374 2.04 2.311 4.25 3.869 6.026l.064.073c.508.58.946 1.083 1.292 1.548 4.519 4.713 11.665 8.677 11.723 8.71.892.657 1.387 1.293 1.44 1.84a.798.798 0 01-.16.58l-.155.162.988.96 18.853-1.324.804-3.684c2.486-10.402 1.967-19.272 1.958-19.33.01-.327.706-3.483 1.266-6.033l.017-.065c1.117-5.08 2.505-11.4 2.772-13.803.116-1.028-.542-1.972-1.675-2.401z"
              />
            </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate the styling of each div that you needs to be removed. I have written a code to add `display:none;` property to the div those you need to remove.

```
const rockDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".rock");

const paperDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".paper");

const scissorsDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".scissors");

for (let i = 0; i < rockDiv.length; i++) {
    rockDiv[i].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  paperDiv[i].style.display = "none";
  scissorsDiv[i].style.display = "none";
});
}

for (let i = 0; i < paperDiv.length; i++) {
    paperDiv[i].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  rockDiv[i].style.display = "none";
  scissorsDiv[i].style.display = "none";
});
}

for (let i = 0; i < scissorsDiv.length; i++) {
    scissorsDiv[i].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  paperDiv[i].style.display = "none";
  rockDiv[i].style.display = "none";
});
}
```

Comment: @Beta V add this code there. It will work.

Comment: in 2022 you should avoid using `style`-statements. Use `classList` and apply changes through CSS.

Comment: Every requirements has their own needs and have different approach. You can't force one approach to all.

Comment: when i put that in the chosen.addEventListner it gives me an error "Declaration or statement expected."

Comment: No don't put chosen.addEventListner

Comment: Copy paste the code above to your codepen js and see

Answer (score 0):

Details commented in example, refer [here](https://markheath.net/post/customize-radio-button-css) for the CSS

```js
// Score counters
let T = 0;
let W = 0;
let L = 0;
// Reference the <form>
const RPS = document.forms.RPS;
// Register <form> to the click event
RPS.onclick = pick;
// Event handler passes Event Object
function pick(e) {
  // Reference ALL form controls
  const IO = this.elements;
  // The tag the user clicked
  const clk = e.target;
  // If the tag clicked is an <input>..
  if (clk.matches('input')) {
    // Disable <label>s
    IO.choices.disabled = true;
    // Add .picked class to <form>
    this.classList.add('picked');
    // Get a random number 0-2
    let r = Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) / 2);
    /* Pass:
    ** All form controls,
    ** Random number,
    ** and #id of clicked <label>
    ** to outcome(IO, r, id)
    */
    switch (clk.id) {
      case 'R':
        console.log('Rock');
        outcome(IO, r, 'R');
        break;
      case 'P':
        console.log('Paper');
        outcome(IO, r, 'P');
        break;
      case 'S':
        console.log('Scissors', );
        outcome(IO, r, 'S');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
/*
** Pass all form controls, random 
** number, and #id of clicked
*/
function outcome(node, vs, user) {
  // 'R'ock, 'P'aper, 'S'cissors
  let rpsA = ['R', 'P', 'S'];
  // Index of user's pick
  const sv = rpsA.indexOf(user);
  /*
  ** Clone the `<label>` that
  ** corresponds to opponent's index
  *//*
  ** Add .vs class to opponent
  *//*
  ** Add opponent to #choices
  */
  const opponent = document.querySelector(`[
    for='${rpsA[vs]}'
  ]`).cloneNode(true);
  opponent.classList.add('vs');
  node.choices.append(opponent);
  /**
  ** One line nested ternary to 
  ** resolve win, lose, or tie
  */
  let result = vs === sv ? 'tied' :
  vs === sv + 1 ? 'lost' :
  vs === 0 && sv === 2 ? 'lost' : 'win';
  // Increment score
  switch (result) {
    case 'tied':
      T++;
      break;
    case 'win':
      W++;
      break;
    case 'lost':
      L++;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  // Display score
  node.w.value = W;
  node.l.value = L;
  node.t.value = T;
  // Array for final outcome
  const roshambo = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
  // Message of outcome
  let msg = `You played ${roshambo[sv]},
  your opponent played ${roshambo[vs]}, you ${result}!`;
  // Display message
  node.msg.value = msg;
}

// Register <form> to reset event
RPS.onreset = reset;

// Resets game
function reset(e) {
  this.classList.remove('picked');
  this.choices.disabled = false;
  document.querySelectorAll('label').forEach(tag => {
    if (tag.classList.contains('vs')) {
      tag.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 1ch/1.1 'Segoe UI'
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

#choices {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input,
output,
button {
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}

legend,
button {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

[type='radio'] {
  display: none
}

[type='radio']:checked+label {
  color: cyan
}

[type='radio']:checked+label * {
  fill: cyan
}

label.vs {
  color: gold
}

label.vs * {
  fill: gold;
}

.picked {
  background: #3B4262;
}

output {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

output::before {
  content: attr(value);
}

#msg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

[type='reset'] {
  position: relative;
  top: 14vh;
}

.as-console-row::after {
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 15% !important;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form id='RPS'>
  <fieldset id='choices'>
    <legend>
      <label>Wins: 
        <output id='w'></output>
      </label>
      <label>Lost: 
        <output id='l'></output> 
      </label>
      <label>Tied: 
        <output id='t'></output> 
      </label><br>
        <output id='msg'></output>
    </legend>
    <!-- rock -->
    <input id='R' name='rps' type='radio'>
    <label for='R' class="rock">
      <svg class="rock svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48">
        <path class="rock"
              fill="#3B4262"
              d="M45.06 12.22c-.642-8.096-9.734-7.269-9.734-7.269-3.837-6.765-9.832-1.865-9.832-1.865-4.606-6.63-10.38-.486-10.38-.486-9.957-1.074-9.571 7.066-9.571 7.066-.234 2.588 1.403 10.593 1.403 10.593-1.477-4.614-4.68-.784-4.68-.784-3.94 6.078-.975 9.405-.975 9.405 5.33 6.246 16.688 13.743 16.688 13.743 4.113 2.356 2.373 4.457 2.373 4.457l24.876-4.11.571-4.718c3.782-11.436-.739-26.032-.739-26.032z"/></svg></label>

    <!-- Paper -->
    <input id='P' name='rps' type='radio'>
    <label for='P' class="paper">
      <svg class="paper svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="49" height="59">
        <path class="paper"
              fill="#3B4262"
              d="M47.125 11.832a2.922 2.922 0 00-1.232-.198c-.57.04-1.029.271-1.302.65-1.604 2.248-2.919 6.493-3.979 9.905-.486 1.577-1.14 3.688-1.612 4.69-.493-2.807.064-13.09.28-17.05l.003-.064c.15-2.751.17-3.234.138-3.446-.238-1.509-.843-2.5-1.799-2.943-.966-.45-2.22-.25-3.572.563-.677.41-.865 1.816-1.446 8.19l-.002.028c-.32 3.502-1.058 11.566-1.965 12.91-1.023-1.88-2.431-12.555-3.039-17.176-.425-3.236-.673-5.094-.84-5.655-.35-1.176-1.83-2.176-3.295-2.232-1.22-.06-2.22.56-2.698 1.638-.894.995-.578 4.292.41 12.102.47 3.718 1.44 11.395.83 12.257-1.219-.133-3.31-4.942-6.215-14.299-.816-2.62-1.068-3.408-1.318-3.753-.494-1.202-2.172-2.129-3.676-2.024a3.183 3.183 0 00-.377.049c-.787.156-2.584.881-2.2 4.226 1.06 4.637 2.213 8.041 3.331 11.346l.023.066c.669 1.98 1.302 3.85 1.89 5.925 1.385 4.9.846 7.94.84 7.975-.046.312-.143.503-.288.57a.556.556 0 01-.195.045c-.44.03-1.098-.26-1.437-.45-.776-1.482-4.636-8.544-8.134-9.524l-.126-.037-.127.012c-1.283.121-2.226.606-2.803 1.441-.914 1.32-.535 3.002-.444 3.34l.052.12c.028.051 2.834 5.165 3.268 7.544.374 2.04 2.311 4.25 3.869 6.026l.064.073c.508.58.946 1.083 1.292 1.548 4.519 4.713 11.665 8.677 11.723 8.71.892.657 1.387 1.293 1.44 1.84a.798.798 0 01-.16.58l-.155.162.988.96 18.853-1.324.804-3.684c2.486-10.402 1.967-19.272 1.958-19.33.01-.327.706-3.483 1.266-6.033l.017-.065c1.117-5.08 2.505-11.4 2.772-13.803.116-1.028-.542-1.972-1.675-2.401z"/></svg></label>

    <!-- Scissors -->
    <input id='S' name='rps' type='radio'>
    <label for='S' class="scissors">
      <svg class="scissors svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="51" height="58">
        <path class="scissors"
              fill="#3B4262"
              d="M13.971 25.702l6.012-8.415c-2.499-.415-7.088-.507-10.846 3.235C3.212 26.421.812 39.163.312 42.248L15.37 57.24c2.711-.232 14.713-1.827 26.279-13.34.122-.249 2.94-2.321.636-4.614-1.1-1.095-2.919-1.074-4.042.044-.572.57-1.461.577-2.021.02-.56-.557-.552-1.443.02-2.012l4.087-4.069c2.076-2.067.119-5.555-2.78-4.717l-3.345 2.851c-.611.53-1.52.439-2.022-.14-.519-.597-.408-1.503.183-2.013 11.687-10.208 9.98-8.979 17.5-15.995 2.809-2.329-.725-6.447-3.493-4.09L28.182 25.45c-.529.448-1.34.457-1.86-.02-.601-.517-.615-1.262-.222-1.85L38.787 3.944c1.854-2.5-1.795-5.277-3.749-2.757L16.28 27.307c-.452.65-1.364.8-1.985.345a1.377 1.377 0 01-.323-1.95z"/></svg></label>
  </fieldset>
  <button type='reset'>Reset</button>
</form>
```